# Swipe Down to Transfer Animation in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, animation

I am trying to make an app where i want to add swipe down to transfer animation where there are two images on the fragment. when user slides down from first image to second image on the fragment screen it should open a new fragment. What exactly should i do to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! this is platform where we can help to solve errors. Please post your code and let us know what error you are facing. If you are looking for code then search on google.